Android BottomSheetDialog: Background blinks between bottom sheet and keyboard when keyboard is expanding (XML)
I have simple bottom sheet with one input field. When it opens I also show keyboard. Here is the sample code.
MainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            showBottomSheet()
        }
    }

    private fun showBottomSheet() {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.Widget_BottomSheetDialog)

        dialog.apply {
            dialog.setContentView(BottomSheetView(this@MainActivity))
            behavior.skipCollapsed = true
            behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            show()
        }
    }
}

Bottom Sheet Content
class BottomSheetView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr){

    private val editText: EditText

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, this, true)

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText)

        editText.requestFocus()
        val imm = context.getSystemService(InputMethodManager::class.java)
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.FrameLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:inputType="text"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</merge>

Bottom Sheet Style
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Widget.BottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Android Manifest has flag android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
Problem statement:
When I open sheet with keyboard there is empty space between keyboard and bottom sheet. How do I handle this if I want bottom sheet and keyboard open simultaneously?
Problem GIF
